# Undefined Firebase Custom Claims

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I want to add a custom claim to the idtoken on registration here is my cloud function for that:

```js
exports.processSignUp = functions.auth.user().onCreate((newUser) => {
  let customClaims = {};
  if (newUser.role === "reader") {
    customClaims.reader = true

  } else if (newUser.role === "writer") {
    customClaims.writer = true
  }
  return admin
    .auth()
    .setCustomUserClaims(newUser.uid, customClaims)
    .then(() => {
      return {
        message: `success`,
      };
    });
});
```

(The newUser object contains a role key that can hold either a string value of writer or reader)

whenever I create a new user the cloud function runs with status ok but later on when I receive the decoded id token there aren't any claims in it so I assume it was null to begin with. I have no idea where my mistake is and couldn't find any documentation that could explain it. Would very much appreciate any help :))

Comment: How are you setting the `role` in `newUser` object? Can you please `console.log(newUser)` and share the response ?

Comment: This is how the newUser object should look like (sorry I don't know how to format code here) 
` {
>    email: 'test1@email.com',
>    password: '123456',
>    confirmPassword: '123456',
>    username: 'test1',
>    role: 'writer'
>  }`

Comment: The `newUser` object is of type `auth.UserRecord` which does not have a role property. To make sure can you please run the `console.log(newUser)` ? So your code is accessing neither the if or else if block

Comment: you are completely right, I've mistaken the argument in the onCreate trigger for the object I am passing to create a user and then nothing is returned from the if, else if block. My goal was to make it in such a way that you are free to choose whether you want to be a reader or a writer and based on your choice a custom claim is added. Should I create a 'role'key-value in the user document in firestore and access it from there in the cloud function and if, else if block?

Comment: please check my answer and let me know if you have any concerns. If that works, you can accept the answer by clicking the check icon so others know the issue is resolved or please feel free to ask further questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newUser` parameter in the function is of type `auth.UserRecord` which does not have any custom properties. It only has [these properties](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/admin/node/admin.auth.UserRecord).

It seems to me that you want to add role - either writer or reader - to a newly created user. Using a custom callable cloud function rather than authentication trigger would be better to avoid race conditions involved in other workarounds.

```
exports.createNewUser = functions.https.onCall((data, context) => {
  const userEmail = data.email;
  const userPassword = data.password
  const role = data.role
  if (!["reader", "writer"].includes(role)) {
    return {error: "Invalid Role"}
  }
  return admin.auth().createUser({ email: userEmail, password: userPassword }).then((newUser) => {
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(newUser.uid, {role: role}).then(() => {
      return {data: "New user created successfully"}
    })
  })
});
```

This will create a new user with role you need. To call this function from your app, follow this code on the client:

```
const createNewUser = firebase.functions().httpsCallable('createNewUser');
createNewUser({ email: "userEmail", password: "userPassword", role: "userRole" })
  .then((result) => {
    // Read result of the Cloud Function.
    const response = result.data.data;
  });
```

Please let me know if you need more clarification.